# How to get Session from Asp.Net Session State with desktop application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session, iis

I have a site created in Asp.Net MVC and it I do the control of Session with following SessionState `<sessionState mode="InProc" stateConnectionString="tcpip=127.0.0.1:42424" sqlConnectionString="" cookieless="false" timeout="60" />`

I need get Sessions from Asp.Net Session State with an desktop application.

How I do this?

Comment: As far i know there is no concept of Session variables in winform, WPF

Comment: Why would you need to do this? Seems a very odd request. You would need to use an session state store which both a ASP.NET app and desktop app can access, like `SQL Server`. Using `SQL Server` as your ASP.NET session state store might help you

Comment: I need to monitor the sessions of my application.

Comment: @JasonEvans Already tried, but I not have all data that I need with SQL Session State.

Comment: What data do you need which isn't included when SQL Server is the session store?